# html form search query string to be displayed on another page - PHP to do the task

Tags: php, html, forms

Ok this has had me banging my head for a while, I have posted on other forums but the info is sketchy at best, I hope you guys can help.

**Scenerio**:

I have a html landing page with a search field. here is the form:

```
<form method="get" action="URL TO EXTERNAL SEARCH" target=content>

    <fieldset>


            <input type="text" class="text" name="keywords" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"maxlength="30" />


            <input type="image" src="images/topnav/btn_search.png" class="button" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

So it obviously takes the queried string and off it goes to an EXTERNAL domain which processors the string and returns the result as an HTML page, which in turn displays it in an Iframe named "content" within the same page.

```
<iframe src="DEFAULT CONTENT" name="content" width="803" height="1200" align="left">
```

Works a treat, however

**PROBLEM**:

I have other pages that DO NOT contain the Iframe but contain the search field.

**WHAT I NEED TO ACHIEVE**:

I need to enter the search string in a html page that DOES NOT contain an Iframe, and display in an Iframe on another html page.

I thought of using javascript/ jquery but due to cross site security issues it doesnt work hence PHP.
I know it can be done but lack the know how.

Any help suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou

*******************UPDATE*************************************

Cheers for the suggestions so far but I have a few queries:

Thanks for the answer but I have a couple of questions so excuse my ignorance.

"landingpage.html" contains a search box but no Iframe to display the search result. "displaypage.html" contains a search box and an Iframe to display search results.

"displaypage.html" works fine; it sends the query string to the EXTERNAL server which returns a HTML page that I send to Iframe in "displaypage.html".

"landingpage.html" needs to direct the search query to "mysearchhandler.php" which in turn processors the query and returns the resulting html page to the Iframe located in "displaypage.html"

This is what I require to happen, I must have the search option on all my pages without an Iframe and be able to direct them to "displaypage.html"

My problem is lack of PHP understanding, so I am very grateful for your help guys but If possible could you place the code in context to relevant pages, it is easier for me to understand where the code goes and what it is doing.

Iam getting the stage where I am considering paying for the code, but I would like to

---

**Anybody ?**

---

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is have a utility page that handles the search via PHP and returns the expected page.

```
<form method="get" action="mysearchhandler.php" target=content>
    <input type="hidden" name="currentPage" value="thispage.php" />
```

And in mysearchhandler.php you could user http_get http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php to pull down the information from the external search page. Use it with http_parse_message http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-message.php

Use the hidden field to tell you which page to return, and update the page to look for the search data.

A simple mysearchhandler.php:

```
$search = clean($_POST['keywords']);
$currentPage = clean($_POST['currenPage']);

$url  = <external search url with get parameters>
$searchResults = http_parse_message(http_get($url))->body;

//Need to validate $currentPage to prevent faked user input
include($currentPage); //Depending on your file system you may need to adjust this
```

Then in your page you could add:

```
if(exists($searchResults))
{
    <Code to display the results>
}
```

Comment: One downside is that the URL displayed in the browser now will be "mysearchhandler.php".  If that's a problem then there are some adjustments that could fix it.

Comment: You could just change the page name to search.php so that it looks something like search.php?keywords=xxx